# Why VS add a toolStrip when I add a sql query?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I have a database and I want to put one of the column in a combobox but I need to exclude duplicate. So in my combobox I choose to use databound and I choose the right databind. Then I choose the right column and it's displayed with duplicate in my combobox.
Here's the part that I don't understand. I add a sql query and basically I just do a distinct and then VS will add me a toolstripbox on the top of my program for no reason and the sql does nothing...
Here is a screenshot just before I add some sql (note that it's just the FillBy, so it should work, it's the request generated by vs) https://i.stack.imgur.com/omOHw.png
And here a screenshot of what happens when I click ok: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCTkZ.png
Why does it add me that??

Thank you

Comment: I just noticed this and am trying to figure out how to prevent this.  I would never want or need this behavior from visual studio...kind of annoying. It's a little late as this is an old question but I will figure out how to prevent this and post in a comment.

Comment: Apparently there is no way to prevent this.  I have no idea why there is an option to add a query from the combobox menu.  I just created another datatable in the dataset designer and am moving on. Would prefer not to have this behavior though :(